# Polymorphic member class for non-virtual base

Tags: c++, arduino, polymorphism, type-erasure, dynamic-dispatch

First if all, of the polymorphism answers I find, it's always like "if the base function is not virtual and the derived object is stored in a pointer of type base, then you cannot call the derived function". But they never tell you what to do when you want to do exactly that. And that's what I need to do.

I have a base class `B` that I have no control over. It's open source (`TwoWire` from Arduino library) and it will not work for others if I make local modifications.

I have a derived class `D` and a user class `U` that I both have control over.

In effect, I want the user to use my class `U` transparently with either a `B` or a `D` as parameter, store it in a member, and use it in member functions.

My futile attempt before learning `virtual` is required on the base class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class B {
public:
    void foo() { cout << "base foo\n"; };
};

class D : public B {
public:
    void foo() { cout << "derived foo\n"; };
};

class U {
public:
    U(B *b) : b(b) { }
    void work() { b->foo(); }
private:
    B *b;
};

int main() {
    B b; U u1{&b}; u1.work(); // "base foo"
    D d; U u2{&d}; u2.work(); // I need this to somehow print "derived foo"
    return 0;
}
```

I could solve this by making an abstract wrapper class and two sub-classes that wrap either `B` or `D`, but that would bring the total number of custom classes to 5. I'm hoping for a solution of just 2 custom classes (or at most 3).

N.B. I'm just starting to learn C++, coming from Java

Answer (score 3):

Since making the member function `virtual` is not a possibility, you have to simulate dynamic dispatch with type erasure:

```
#include <functional>

class U {
public:
    template <class C>
    U(C* p)
        : f{[p]{ p->foo(); }}
    {
    }
    void work()
    {
        f();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> f;
};
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oWKP1XxMH0kOgxzH))

Note that functions in Java are virtual by default.  Not in C++.

Comment: Apparently for Arduino I have access only to a limited amount of header files, even if I set the compiler to use C++11, so I'm hoping for a grammatical or architectural solution, not a stdlib solution.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Then, basically, reinvent `std::function` and the binders.  Should be possible in theory.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I reinvented `std::function` [a couple of months ago](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221921).  That may give you some inspiration.  You only need to implement the features you need (the `operator()` and the function base).

Comment: I just studied your code in detail. Does that mean for every single function I want to call on `B` I have to add a member?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Under this approach, yes.  Alternatively, you can use `std::variant` if you know all the derived classes you are going to be using.  Then, you can use `std::visit`. In either case, type erasure only works on a finite set of types.